# What expression statements in ECMAScript actually are

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-6, grammar

Let's say that at some point of a parsing process, I've already traversed the following grammar derivation:

```
Script -> ScriptBody -> StatementList -> ExpressionStatement -> Expression
```

Here comes the trouble. According to the spec, an `Expression` within an `ExpressionStatement` can only end up as an `AssignmentExpression` or a sequence of those. However, statements like

```
a;
12;
"some text";
```

definitely are expression statements (as far as I understand), at the same time not being any of the `AssignmentExpression`'s possible subtypes. They do not resolve to a syntax error in my browsers.

Is it a particular implementation's or engine's feature that these statements return the value or am I missing something in the spec? Maybe, those are not `AssignmentExpressions` at all and I'm mistaking them for something else?

Comment: Clause 13.5 in the Syntax section: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-expression-statement links to 12.16, Comma Operator: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-comma-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a look at the definition of [`AssignmentExpression`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-AssignmentExpression), you'll see that it resolves to  , for example, `AssignmentExpression` -> `ConditionalExpression` -> `LogicalORExpression` -> `LogicalANDExpression` -> `BitwiseORExpression` -> `BitwiseXORExpression` -> `BitwiseANDExpression` -> `EqualityExpression` -> `RelationalExpression` -> `ShiftExpression` -> `AdditiveExpression` -> `MultiplicativeExpression` -> `ExponentiationExpression` -> `UnaryExpression` -> `UpdateExpression` -> `LeftHandSideExpression` -> `NewExpression` -> `MemberExpression` -> `PrimaryExpression` -> `Literal` -> `StringLiteral`.

So `"some text"` is a valid `AssignmentExpression`. The same goes for other literals and variable references.